# Ant and jar directory structure

Tags: java, ant, jar

I have the next directory structure for my personal project:

```
mines/
 build.xml
 build/
 build/classes/
 build/jar/
 src/minesweeper
 src/minesweeper/view/
 src/minesweeper/model/
 res/img/
```

and my `build.xml` file is:

```
<project>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/minesweeper-clone.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="minesweeper.Minesweeper"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/minesweeper-clone.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

In Ubuntu I do:

```
$ant compile jar run
```

and everything is ok. But if I do:

```
$java -jar minesweeper.jar
```

the program runs, but the icons are not displayed.

In my `src/minesweeper/view/GameFrame.java` class I have:

```
private static final String NEW_GAME_ICON = "res/img/new_game.png";
```

and `new_game.png` is in `res/img/new_game.png`

I know if I do:

```
$java -jar build/jar/minesweeper-clone.jar
```

it works perfect and the icons are displayed, but I want to execute only the jar file in windows (without the whole directory of my project).

Thanks.

**EDIT**
The way I access the resources is:

```
JMenuItem newGameItem1 = new JMenuItem("New game", new ImageIcon(NEW_GAME_ICON));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to include the resource into the jar itself, and read the file using this API:

[getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

So first you need to make sure the resource is in the jar (open it up and make sure it's there), and two make sure you are using an API call such as that and not File IO mechanisms (because the image will be in the jar; not on the filesystem).

Comment: Thanks. The icons are not in the jar. Do I need to modify the build.xml to add the icons?

Comment: @enrmarc ... If you want to have everything self-contained in the jar, then of course.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've added the icons, but the problem continues. The res/ folder is at the same level of META-INF/ and minesweeper/. I think the problem is the images path, but if I change "res/img/new_game.png" to "../../res/img/new_game.png" then when I execute 'ant jar'the icons are not displayed. If I do 'java -jar minesweeper.jar' the icons are displayed. So is there any way to execute the jar with ant and java -jar and display the icons?

Comment: Until you are using that method I posted earlier, you are not reading from the jar.  That method returns a stream.  A stream, once read, can be placed into a byte[].  And ImageIcon has a constructor that takes a byte[].  Glue it all together and try your app again.

Comment: Thanks @sethcall, now it works. I've included all the project in the jar (except build/ directory) and I've used the getResource() method.